# How do you get the params on a Route Handler with React Router

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I am trying to redirect a route to another route, and pass some params, like so:

```
var UnAuthenticatedClass = React.creatClass({
  statics: {
    willTransitionTo: function (transition) {
      if(!isLoggedIn()) {
        transition.redirect('signin', {
          originalTransition: transition
        });
    }
  }
...
```

My signin route:

```
var SignIn = React.createClass({
  componentDidMount: function() {
    console.log(this.getParams().originalTransition); // returns undefined
  },
...
```

No matter what I put in as params, this.getParams() returns an empty object. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`this.getParams()` gets the params as defined by the `Route` definition's `path` property; you can't just pass anything you want and expect them to show up in params of the resulting handler. You'll need to stash that data somewhere else (e.g. unrelated to the router) and fetch them on the other side.